# Heroku Europe region: "Application error" when trying to fork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying out Heroku's new support for the [Europe region](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/4/24/europe-region).

However, I always get a meaningless error trying to fork my app:

```
$ heroku fork --region eu
Creating fork testapp-989... done
Copying slug... done
Adding blitz:250... done
Adding memcache:5mb... ! Application error
```

There is nothing about this in the output of "heroku logs". 
I filed a ticket with Heroku support but they've been unresponsive for a week.
(note this app is on the free plan, that's probably the reason...).

I don't know where to start debugging this. Is this an issue with the Heroku client / Heroku toolbelt ? Is this a server-side thing?
Any other people with similar issues?

Comment: This does not look like the right command to fork "heroku fork --region eu". Or did you just shorten it in this post?

Comment: Yes, it's the right command, please see the link I posted to their docs.

Comment: maybe the memcache add-on is not available in europe.

Comment: @kch: you're right! I checked https://addons.heroku.com/memcache and it says "only available in the US region". I hadn't checked that before as I had another addon that also wasn't available, and when forking I got the message "xxx is only available in region us".
Please add your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @TomDeLeu done. you might also want to report the different behavior at http://help.heroku.com. You should always get the availability error message from fork.

Comment: Yep, reported it now in the support ticket I had already opened with them, thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't result in an application error - it should just print out a provisioning failed error and move on. We're investigating.

Comment: ok thanks Ryan. FYI the same issue ("application error") occurred with another addon: zerigo_dns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Memcache add-on is not available in europe:

http://addons.heroku.com/memcache